# br tag doesn't work inside dynamically created html

Tags: php, html

I have some dynamic html and wants a new line, i.e. `<br>` tag after each `<img>` tag.

```
for ($i=1; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result_p); $i++){
$row_p = mysqli_fetch_array($result_p);
echo "<img id='". $i . "' src='". $row_p['url'] ."' width='200' height='200' alt='img'>";
echo "<br>";  // doesn't work
}
```

I checked the resulting html markup on W3C validation service - there is no error, but `<br>` tag still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? What happens?

Comment: @MarkM, Nothing happens. Simply, there is no new line.

Comment: So the images just line up next to each other, left to right?

Comment: Let's see the resulting HTML—the smallest version that produces your "doesn't work". The PHP's not that useful for diagnosis, and the rest of the HTML document may be influencing the result.

Comment: @MarkM, Yes, that's it. Images are placed next to each other, left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of better solutions in order to have what you want:

**Option 1:**
Put the images list in an unorderlist  putting a display:block attribute to li tags

```
<ul class="images">
  <li> 
    <img src=""/>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Then in your css stylesheet:

```
ul.images li{display:block}
```

**Option 2:**
Just surround you `img` tag with a block element : `<div>, <p>` for example and use css for giving it more space between images

Comment: Thanks, this is maybe a better solution, but I still want to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Please, publish your html output: right click view source. That's the only way of knowing why it does not work beacause it should. BR should add a line break after each img as default

Comment: For option 2: instead of wrapping it in an extra unnecessary element, you could use CSS and use display: block on the images. Same result, less code.